# Combine two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

I am using this SQL statement to count how many times a particular piece of data occurs in column `Info_Data` in `Table_1`. In its current hard coded form it returns a value of `9`

```
SELECT Staff_No, Info_Data, COUNT(*) cCount
            FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
            WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data_1' 
            GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data
```

I then have another SQL statement that checks to see if a row exists in `Table_2`, if it does not, insert a row and update the data. If it does ,just update the data.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = 1)
      BEGIN
         UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
                       SET Column_Value = 9
                       WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = 1
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL (Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index, Column_Value)
                       VALUES (3201, 2016, 6, 1, 9)
      END
```

Both these statements are working how they are supposed to.

But I can't find a way to combine the two statements, I tried `JOIN` , `MERGE` with no luck.
Being that the value that the first statement returns is `9`, I want to replace the hard coded `9` on this line `SET Column_Value = 9` and the `Column_Value` columns value `9` on this line `VALUES (3201, 2016, 6, 1, 9)` with result of the first statement

This obviously is incorrect, but to illustrate what I am sort of trying to do.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = 1)
BEGIN
   UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
                   SET Column_Value = SELECT Staff_No, Info_Data, COUNT(*) cCount
                                                 FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
                                                 WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data_1' 
                                                 GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data
                   WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL (Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index, Column_Value)
                   VALUES (3201, 2016, 6, 1, SELECT Staff_No, Info_Data, COUNT(*) cCount
                                                 FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
                                                 WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data_1' 
                                                 GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data)
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query returns more than one column and you can't use it to update or insert a single column. Instead, make it to return only `count()` and try

```
UPDATE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
SET Column_Value = (
     SELECT COUNT(*)  
     FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
     WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data_1' 
     GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data
    )
WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6 AND Column_Index = 1
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL 
(Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index, Column_Value)
SELECT 3201, 2016, 6, 1, COUNT(*) 
     FROM Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL
     WHERE Staff_No = 3201 AND Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1' AND Info_Data = 'Data_1' 
     GROUP BY Staff_No, Info_Data
```

As you can see, in INSERT there is no VALUES construction, read http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp for more details. Also see how to [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server).

P.S. Using of BEGIN/END is not required for single queries and they could be skipped.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Thank you that works great.

Answer (score 1):

The redundancy in the two statements in the accepted answer bothers me i.e. a change to one business rules would need to be changed in at least two places.

So here's my attempt at writing the equivalent `MERGE` statement (trust you can see the potential for a table-valued parameter here):

```
WITH Params AS
(
 SELECT * 
   FROM ( VALUES ( 3201, 2016, 6, 1 ) )
        AS T ( Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index )
),
ParamsWithCount AS 
(
 SELECT p.Staff_No, p.Year_D, p.Month_D, p.Column_Index, COUNT(*) AS Column_Value
   FROM Params p
        JOIN Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL t
           ON p.Staff_No = t.Staff_No
  WHERE t.Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1'
        AND t.Info_Data = 'Data_1'
  GROUP 
     BY p.Staff_No, p.Year_D, p.Month_D, p.Column_Index, t.Info_Data
)
MERGE Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Count_TBL t
   USING ParamsWithCount p
      ON t.Staff_No = p.Staff_No
         AND t.Year_D = p.Year_D
         AND t.Month_D = p.Month_D
         AND t.Column_Index = p.Column_Index
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET Column_Value = p.Column_Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ( Staff_No, Year_D, Month_D, Column_Index, Column_Value )
      VALUES ( p.Staff_No, p.Year_D, p.Month_D, p.Column_Index, p.Column_Value );
```

I also can't help wondering whether the hard-coded logic of `Date_Data BETWEEN '2016/6/1' AND '2016/7/1'` in fact relates to the parameter values `Year_D = 2016 AND Month_D = 6`.

---

This could be made into a proc with a table-valued parameter in place of the `params` CTE above e.g. something like:

```
CREATE TYPE Staff_Count_Type AS TABLE
(
 Staff_No INT,
 Year_D INT,
 Month_D INT,
 Column_Index INT
);

CREATE PROCEDURE UpateOrCreateStaffCount
@params Staff_Count_Type READONLY
AS
WITH ParamsWithCount AS 
(
 SELECT p.Staff_No, p.Year_D, p.Month_D, p.Column_Index, COUNT(*) AS Column_Value
   FROM @params p
        JOIN Staff_Manager.dbo.Staff_Time_TBL ...snipped...
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes the hard coded month and year dirrectly correlates to the date. When putting this into C# I will not have any hard coded data at all. I am not sure I follow what you mean with the `table-valued parameter` Thanks again. Up vote for the help and nice answer. BTW, works great.

Comment: Updated with an outline of a proc with a table-valued parameter.